# kendo grid row should be selected while editing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that is bind with 4 input box . when I click on a grid row : inputs value is set with the columns data from that row .

and if from first input I go to second input , the grid row exit selected style , but I want to be selected while user is busy with editing .

I use this code in dataBound code :

```
 var contact = $("#contact-grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find('tr[data-uid="' + this._selectedContact.uid + '"]');
    $("#contact-grid").data("kendoGrid").current(contact);
```

but it doesnt work and close edit view after blur from an input to another

Answer (score 0):

ok I find :) . and post it to help others ,maybe one day ...

should write this code on grid dataBinding event :

```
private _onGridDataBinding(e){
 if(e.action == "itemchange")
   {e.preventDefault();}
}
```